# Detect when user moves to specific screens react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using react-navigation with react-native and I have bottomTabs for navigation, I have a screen to edit some info, I want to be able to detect when the user tries to move from that screen to other "specific" screens to trigger a certain action.

what I tried:

```
useEffect(
    () =>
        navigation.addListener('blur', (e) => {
            // Prompt the user before leaving the screen
                Alert.alert('You haven’t saved your changes,[
                    { text: translate('yes'), style: 'cancel' },
                    {
                        text: translate('no'),
                        style: 'destructive',
                        onPress: () => navigation.navigate('EditProfileScreen'),
                    },
                ])
        }),
    [navigation]
)
```

But the above triggers when I move to any screen, while I want it only to be triggered for specific screens.
Any insights?

Comment: When the user clicks on bottom tabs, check your condition there, if you are happy, then navigate the user, else alert him

Comment: Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: I have added an answer elaborating

Answer (score 1):

You should remove listener after leaving this component, so that it does not continue to other one:

```
const checkBeforeLeaving = (e) => {
    // Prompt the user before leaving the screen
    Alert.alert('You haven’t saved your changes,[
        { text: translate('yes'), style: 'cancel' },
        {
            text: translate('no'),
            style: 'destructive',
            onPress: () => navigation.navigate('EditProfileScreen'),
        },
    ])
}
```

Then [return with a clearing function in `useEffect()` to clear side-effects on component unmount](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1):

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Adding side effect on component mount
  navigation.addListener('blur', checkBeforeLeaving);

  // Specify how to clean up this effect on component-unmount:    
  return () => navigation.removeListener('blur', checkBeforeLeaving)
}, [navigation])
```

In this way, this side-effect will be limited to this specific component only.